# Load image into ExifInterface

Tags: android, exif

Im trying to load a hardcoded image into the android ExifInterface but it can't seem to find it. This is what I am trying:

```
ExifInterface mExif = new ExifInterface("images/IMG_20150411_194725.jpg");
```

The images is located in res/images directory. Is there something i need to do for android to pick it up?

Comment: What you want to do  ?

Comment: Just load a hardcoded image into my code so I can extract the meta data

Comment: Can you please explain ?

Comment: Not sure how else I can explain - just as a proof of concept, I'm trying to load an image into my code so I can extract the metadata such as time photo was taken, GPS coordinates etc. But android won't allow me to load the image in using the above code as it can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `res/` usually refers to resources. Not only do those only exist as files on your development machine, but you cannot invent new resource directories, and there is nothing named `res/images/` in Android.

Second, `ExifInterface` only loads files off of the filesystem, not resources. After all, it would be completely pointless for a developer to want to use `ExifInterface` on a resource. Resources are read-only, so you cannot use `ExifInterface` to modify EXIF headers in a resource. And rather than wasting users' time, CPU, and battery reading in a read-only image file to extract metadata, developers would do that ahead of time, putting that data somewhere else, such as string or integer resources.

Third, `ExifInterface` needs a fully-qualified path to the file on the filesystem. So even if you have a file somewhere in the filesystem in an `images/` directory (e.g., created using `getFilesDir()` as as base), you would need to provide a fully-qualified path to that file.