# How get Exif from R.drawable.image jpg?

Tags: java, android

I create android project
I hava  **image.jpg** with geo
image.jpg local in android project resources:

R.drawable.image

I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        />
    <ScrollView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exif"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String imagefile =Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.anton.gpsgeotag/drawable/image").toString();
    ImageView image;
    TextView Exif;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        Exif = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.exif);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
        Uri path=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.anton.gpsgeotag/ + R.drawable.image");
        Exif.setText(ReadExif(imagefile));
    }

    String ReadExif(String file){
        String exif="Exif: " + file;
        try {
            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(file);

            exif += "\nIMAGE_LENGTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH);
            exif += "\nIMAGE_WIDTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH);
            exif += "\n DATETIME: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
            exif += "\n TAG_MAKE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);
            exif += "\n TAG_MODEL: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL);
            exif += "\n TAG_ORIENTATION: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
            exif += "\n TAG_WHITE_BALANCE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE);
            exif += "\n TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH);
            exif += "\n TAG_FLASH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH);
            exif += "\nGPS related:";
            exif += "\n TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP);
            exif += "\n TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP);
            exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LATITUDE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
            exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
            exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
            exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
            exif += "\n TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD);

            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "finished",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return exif;
    }
}
```

Why does not it work, I don't know

Image.jpg in res/drawable/

Where an error??
[image]

Comment: are any exceptions being thrown or any errors being logged?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work ?

Comment: I getting null in all textview

Comment: drawables are recompressed in png

Comment: why is that Exif in blue color(odd man out there)...

Comment: ExifInterface  requires a file(name), not an URI. Therefore you can not load resources in ExifInterface. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697530/load-image-into-exifinterface

Comment: I have String imagefile ="/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/image1.jpg"; don't work